# Insertions in shma koleinu

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, shemoneh-esrei, artscroll

The Artscroll siddur offers two insertions that one can add to the bracha of shma koleinu every day, one asking forgiveness for sin and the other asking for livelihood. What are the sources for these insertions, and why are they not found in the Koren, Metzudah, or Rinat Yisrael siddurim?

Comment: Could you edit the question to say what those insertions are?

Comment: @MonicaCellio the exact text varies from siddur to siddur, but there are usually two - one asking forgiveness for sin and the other asking for livelihood.

Comment: Artscroll likes to add kabalistic things to their siddurim, and sometimes adds chasidic minhagim to ashkenaz siddur even if it was not traditionally done that way.  Because of this Artscroll has received a lot of criticism from minhag purists.  But I don't know the sources of those precise prayers.  As an aside, you are allowed to add any prayer you like during Shma Kolainu

Comment: and I have been reciting the one for livelihood now regularly for about 10 years

Answer (score 1):

I have noted that these additions are not included in any nusach Ashkenaz siddurim I have seen, while they are included in every nusach Sefard siddur I have seen.  If they are included in the nusach Ashkenaz Artscroll siddur, it might be out of a desire for some conformity and unity between that and their Sefard siddur.  Unfortunately, I have no source, and this is purely speculative.

Answer (score 1):

The **Magen Avraham** in O.C. 119:1 quotes from the Sefer Hakavanos that it is a good thing to say these two prayers in Shema Koleinu.  He additionally sources the Zohar Shemos 109-110.  The **Mishna Berura** (119:4) cites this Magen Avraham as halacha.  Artscroll often inserts additions based upon the advice of the Mishna Berura, as you will find in other places in the Artscroll siddur (Parts of the Korbanos section, for example).